# JUnit not recognized in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to integrate and setup the JUnit 5 libraries with IntelliJ on my linux distro. I added JUnit to my gradle, and built it using gradle. But I am still seeing an error on my unit tests prompting me to "add junit to my classpath" even though it already is. [image]

Here is my build.gradle

```
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'com.techchallenge'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1')
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1')
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

*UPDATE*
See screenshot. I added the dependency and it is still prompting me to add the junit to my classpath though I already did
[image: updated intellij]

***UPDATE 2***
I updated the build.gradle and also did gradlew clean build test which was successful. But it is still showing the error with my junit annotations- and keeps prompting me to add junit 5.4 to my classpath though it is there.

```
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'com.techchallenge'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'

    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2')
    testRuntime('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.4.2')

}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

[image: errors on intellij]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. After fixing the gradle build as shown in the jupiter example project (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-getting-started-example-projects), it still did not work.
Cleaning the caches and restarting the IDE did also not work.

What fixed it for me was, I closed the IDE, deleted the `.idea` and `.gradle` folders in the project and started the IDE again.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with `JUnit 5` using `Maven`. I discovered that IDEA had created some `*.iml` files where it should not have. I had one in the test folder called `test.iml`. After deleting them the problems went away.

Please check if IDEA did not create some sneaky modules unexpectedly.

I see in the screenshot that you have one of those:

[image]

My advice is to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It should recognise your setup. You may try adding junit5 dependencies (which is how junit5 is added creating a Gradle project from scratch using IntelliJ's `New Project` option) as below then reload your Gradle Project.

```
    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
        testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    }
```

You may try `File | Invalidate caches/Restart...` option to get rid of odd issues if your project runs tests successfully using `gradle test` cli command

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html

You have to use the right imports for Junit 5, You are using Junit4 imports. Since version 5 `@Test`, `Assertions`, etc are within `org.junit.jupiter.api` package. e.g:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class DummyTest {

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {

    }

    @Test
    void name() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }
```

You may look into [junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.7.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle)

Comment: I updated my question- still see the same weird 'add to classpath' error

Comment: What else can i do? i tried deleting the .gradle folder and also invalidating the cache and rebuilding.... And i still got the error?

Comment: You imported the JUnit 4 classes, see my updated answer, use the right imports & run `gradle test` command in a terminal to check whether your project config is OK, IntelliJ gets dizzy sometimes with gradle projects

Comment: I updated the question. I fixed the imports and did the gradle test command- and it says that it built successfully. but i still have the errors - and it prompts me to add the junit 5 to my classpath though it is already there

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have correctly setup gradle inside your intellij like for maven

and make sure You have installed JUnit plugin for IntelliJ IDEA,

[image]

you can even point gradle to your local repository like

```
repositories {
  flatDir {
   dirs 'C:/path/to/local/directory'
  }
}
dependencies {
compile name: 'name-of-jar'
}
```

Comment: i used gradle though- do i need to have maven installed?

Comment: @Linkx_lair you don't need to install Maven in order to use Gradle